# How can i delete a paragraph that contain one or more words?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I´m trying to delete the paragraph that contain a specific word. I achieved the problem, how can i deleted with more words.

VBA

```
Dim check As Boolean
Dim search As String
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim tempStr As String
Dim txt As String

search = "word1","word2" #word2 doesn´t work

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    txt = para.Range.Text
    tempStr = LCase(txt)
    check = InStr(tempStr, search)

    If check = True Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a list of strings in a string type in VBA. You need to create a collection or array and iterate through the elements checking each one. I would use a collection personally.

```
dim search as Collection
dim colliter as variant

search.add "word1"
search.add "word2"

for each colliter in search
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        txt = para.Range.Text
        tempStr = LCase(txt)
        check = InStr(tempStr, colliter)
    next
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very inefficient - there is no need to loop through all the paragraphs. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd(), i As Long
ArrFnd = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six")
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ArrFnd(i)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found = True
        .Paragraphs.First.Range.Text = vbNullString
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```